# mocking mongodb with phpunit

Tags: php, mongodb, phpunit, mockery

I have a save function for create new document with mongoDB

```
public function save(User $user): User
{
    $result = $this->usersCollection->insertOne($user->getUser());
    $user->setId($result->getInsertedId());
    return $user;
}
```

And Change __construct for implemet test

```
public function __construct($db = null)
{
    if (is_null($db)) {
        parent::__construct();
    } else {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    $this->usersCollection = $this->db->users;
}
```

I write this test for save function

```
public function testSave()
{
    $mongo = \Mockery::mock('MongoDB\Client');
    $mongo->shouldReceive('insertOne')->andReturn("ok");
    $mongo->shouldReceive('selectDatabase')->andReturnSelf();

    $user = new User('jack', '0015005050');
    $um = new UserMongoDB($mongo);
    $res = $um->save($user);
}
```

everything works well but my problem is `$result->getInsertedId()` How to I can Mock this function?

> Error : Call to a member function getInsertedId() on string

Answer (score 1):

The return type of the `insertOne` method must be an instance of `InsertOneResult` (see [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.2/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-insertOne/)). At the moment you are returning the string "ok". You could keep going and make `insertOne` return a mock of `InsertOneResult`. This may work but you are at the gate to mocking hell. Personally, I'd write integration tests for the save method. Mocking the save method in other unit tests is way easier than mocking the low level MongoDB stuff all over the place.